# Can I specify more than two DNS in dd-wrt? Different company DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, router, dnsmasq, opendns

Right now my "Additional DNSMasq options" is as follows:
no-resolv
strict-order
server=208.67.222.222
server=208.67.222.220

1. can I specify OpenDns for the first and genuity for the second (i.e. 4.2.2.1)?
2. can I specify more than 2 IP addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and yes.  DNSMasq allows as many -S (--server) options as you like.  There is no issue using different DNS providers (in fact, it's a good idea).

http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html

Comment: cool!  So dd-wrt will just try the next server if one is down?

Comment: Yes, well, more correctly DNSMasq will try the servers in order.